# single vs double quotes in WHERE clause returning different results

Tags: sql

It seemed that Athena was including CSV column headers in my query results. I recreated the tables with the DDL included below using `TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` to remove the headers.

I'm running the following queries to validate that the `CREATE TABLE` DDL worked. The only difference between the queries below is the use of single vs double quotes in the WHERE clause. The issue is that I'm getting different result when running them.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
  file_name
FROM table
WHERE file_name = "file_name"
```

The query above returns the actual data (see sample table below), rather than only rows where the file_name field is "file_name".

```
+-------+--------------------+
| Row # |     file_name      |
+-------+--------------------+
|     1 |                    |
|     2 | 1586786323.8194735 |
|     3 |                    |
|     4 | 1586858857.3117666 |
|     5 | 1586858857.3117666 |
|     6 | 1586858857.3117666 |
|   ... |                    |
+-------+--------------------+
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
  file_name
FROM table
WHERE file_name = 'file_name'
```

The query above returns `no results`, as expected if the CSV column headers are not being included in the results.

I'm quite confused by the first query returning any results at all. I've scoured the AWS documentation at this point and doesn't seem I did anything wrong with the DDL and SQL should not care whether I use single vs. double quotes. What am I missing here?

**DDL:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table` (
     `file_name` string,
     `ticker` string,
     ...
     )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'separatorChar'=',')
LOCATION
  's3://{bucket_name}/{folder}/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Comment: `"file_name"` is an identifier, in this case your column with that name. `'file_name'` is a string literal.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: Of course they are returning different things - those are two different queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand on Gordon's answer a little. Your first query:

```
SELECT
  file_name
FROM table
WHERE file_name = "file_name"
```

In this case, the double quotes are causing the query engine to treat `"file_name"` as a column identifier, not a value, so that query is functionally the same as:

```
SELECT
  file_name
FROM table
WHERE file_name = file_name
```

Obviously (when written that way) the condition is always true, so the full table is returned.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you for clarifying with the code example. It also answers the follow up question I posted as a comment on Gordon's answer. I wish I could mark both of the answers as the best.

Comment: Glad it helped! And thanks for upvoting both answers. That's definitely the right way to acknowledge both posters. If you wanted to give him the check mark for getting here first, I'd totally understand.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes are the SQL standard for delimiting strings.

Double quotes are used for escaping delimiters.  So `"file_name"` refers to the column of that name.  Some databases also accept double quotes for strings.  That is just confusing.  Don't do that.

In your original tags, for instance, Hive uses backticks to escape identifiers and double quotes for strings.  Presto uses double quotes (which is the standard) to delimit identifiers.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, writing ```WHERE file_name = "file_name"``` is saying give me rows where the column file_name is equal to the column file_name rather than give me rows where the file_name value is 'file_name'. I ran the double quote query using ```WHERE file_name = "ticker"``` to check my understanding, but am still a bit confused...the results were a bunch of empty rows rather than ```no results```. Would you mind explaining why this is the case? I understand that I shouldn't do this, just trying to understand why the query works at all vs throwing error.